# Build Error with no Logical/Syntax Errors

Tags: c#, build

I was beginning to create a command line program that allowed me to complete problem 4 on Project Euler.

https://projecteuler.net/problem=4

While I was in the middle of scripting the program, I decided to debug (I'm using Visual Studio Suite 2015)

When it began, it had a message pop up and show that the program itself has "Build Errors."

I have absolutely no idea what happened.

In the version below (C#), the script has no logical errors, and it has no syntax errors either.

Could you please tell me what's wrong with it?
Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Problem_4
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Check Palindrome
            //Not complete code.

            int originalValue = 9009;
            int oppositeValue = 0; ;
            int carryOppositeValue;
            int placeValue = 0;
            bool completedCycle = false;
            int numCycles = 0;

            int numCycles2 = 0;

            int[] array = { 0 };

            for(placeValue = numCycles; completedCycle; placeValue++)
            {

                array[placeValue] = originalValue % 10;
                originalValue = originalValue / 10;

                if(originalValue >= 0)
                {

                    numCycles++;

                } else
                {

                    completedCycle = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("The number has " + numCycles + "Place Values");

                }

            }



            for(placeValue = 0; placeValue < 50; placeValue += 10)
            {

                if (numCycles2 == 0)
                {
                    oppositeValue = array[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    carryOppositeValue = placeValue * array[placeValue / 10];
                    oppositeValue += carryOppositeValue;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not adding in comments... If it would help, I can put them in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled this code and got no errors. I would suggest doing a build/clean.

If that doesn't work I would delete the bin and obj folders then recompile.